# How can see qDebug and Unit test Macro (QCOMPARE etc) result in jenkins console

Tags: qt, unit-testing, jenkins, console, qdebug

I try to do that unit test results are printed in jenkins console. But I can not do. I am thinking that jenkins build console can not print qDebug. And I tried it can not print qdebug. But std::cout is working. How can I proceed?

Thank you. I tried that you said. But It can not work. It gives error. error: C3861: 'qInstallMsgHandler': identifier not found

```
//! [0]

#include <QtTest/QtTest>
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>
void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const char *msg)
{
 switch (type) {
 case QtDebugMsg:
     fprintf(stderr, "Debug: %s\n", msg);
     break;
 case QtWarningMsg:
     fprintf(stderr, "Warning: %s\n", msg);
     break;
 case QtCriticalMsg:
     fprintf(stderr, "Critical: %s\n", msg);
     break;
 case QtFatalMsg:
     fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: %s\n", msg);
     abort();
 }
 }
 class TestQString: public QObject
 {
Q_OBJECT
public:
TestQString(){
    qInstallMsgHandler(myMessageOutput);
}
private slots:
void toUpper();

};
//! [0]

//! [1]
void TestQString::toUpper()
{
QString str = "Hello";
QCOMPARE(str.toUpper(), QString("HELLO"));
qDebug() << "hello";
std::cout << "Hello, world!\n\n";
}
//! [1]

//! [2]
QTEST_MAIN(TestQString)
#include "testqstring.moc"
//! [2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QT4 Version:
Try to implement your own Messagehandler like this:

```
void MessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const char* msg)
{
    //in this function, you can write the message to any stream!
    switch (type) {
      case QtDebugMsg:
        std::cout << msg << ::std::endl;
        break;
    //case QtWarningMsg:
    //  fprintf(stderr, "Warning: %s\n", msg);
    //  break;
    //case QtCriticalMsg:
    //  fprintf(stderr, "Critical: %s\n", msg);
    //  break;
    //case QtFatalMsg:
    //  fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: %s\n", msg);
    //  abort();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
qInstallMsgHandler(MessageOutput);

QApplication App(argc, argv);

Testapp Updater;
Updater.doSomething();

return App.exec();
}
```

Every DebugMsg is redirected to std::cout.

Same example for QT5 [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler)

Comment: thank you. I changed qInstallMsgHandler to qInstallMessageHandler. But it gives error again. "qInstallMessageHandler : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(QtMsgType,const char *)' to 'QtMessageHandler' None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type"

Comment: yes you are right qinstallMessagehandler is the correct declaration in qt 5. Which qt Version do you use?

Comment: You are using qt 5. My example was qt 4. My fault. Use the example link for qt 5 version. myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg) has more parameters.